# Codeigniter 3 blog application: redirecting to the updated post fails

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I am working on a basic (just 2 tables: *authors* and *posts*) blog application in Codeigniter 3.1.8.

I have an edit post functionality, using an update form:

```
<?php echo form_open("posts/update"); ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" id="pid" value="<?php echo $post->id; ?>">
      <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('title')) echo 'has-error';?>">
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" value="<?php echo $post->title; ?>">
        <?php if(form_error('title')) echo form_error('title'); ?> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('desc')) echo 'has-error';?>">
        <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" class="form-control" placeholder="Short decription" value="<?php echo $post->description; ?>">
        <?php if(form_error('desc')) echo form_error('desc'); ?> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('body')) echo 'has-error';?>">
        <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Add post body"><?php echo $post->content; ?></textarea>
        <?php if(form_error('body')) echo form_error('body'); ?> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success">
      </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

In the **Posts_model** model I have the method responsible with updating the post:

```
public function update_post() {
    $data = [
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'description' => $this->input->post('desc'),
        'content' => $this->input->post('body')
    ];
    $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));
    return $this->db->update('posts', $data);
}
```

In the Posts controller, I have 2 methods, for editing and updating the post:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);
    $data['tagline'] = 'Edit the post "' . $data['post']->title . '"';
    $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('edit');
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');
}

public function update() {
    $this->Posts_model->update_post();
    // Redirect to the updated post

}
```

In my update() method, I was unable to redirect to the updated post. The `redirect($this->agent->referrer());` line only brings me back to the *update form*. Where I want to redirect to is the *just updated post*. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post vars should be handled in your controller:

```
public function update() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $data = [
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'description' => $this->input->post('desc'),
        'content' => $this->input->post('body')
    ];
    // Update post
    $this->Posts_model->update_post($id, $data);
    // Redirect to the updated post
    redirect('posts/post/' . $id);
}
```

Model:

```
public function update_post($id, $data) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->update('posts', $data);
}
```

Note: if you want to do it your way, then simply return the id in the model function and redirect based on the return of the function in `update()`

Comment: I would also **highly** suggest validating that the information is there. Otherwise a call to `update` from browser will yield in a failed db call.